# Is ESV translation of "opposite that mountain" in Exodus 34:3 justified?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 34:3 New International Version

> No one is to come with you or be seen anywhere on the mountain; not even the flocks and herds may graze **in front of** the mountain."

in front of
אֶל־ (’el-)
Preposition
Strong's Hebrew 413: Near, with, among, to

English Standard Version

> No one shall come up with you, and let no one be seen throughout all the mountain. Let no flocks or herds graze **opposite** that mountain.”

How is it that ESV translates it as *opposite*?

Comment: see also https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H5921

Comment: I think you need to look at this: https://biblehub.com/text/exodus/34-3.htm

Comment: The [Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/34-3.htm) indicates there are two prepositions there אֶל־ and מ֖וּל and the Biblehub Interlinear gives 'before the front of'. YLT gives 'over against'. I find the comment made by @Lucian to be quite inappropriate and I think it would be desirable if such condescending remarks were to cease on this website. Flagged for Moderator assessment and I have cancelled the down-vote with an up-vote.

Comment: @NigelJ: It is a simple factual remark. And there's nothing wrong with asking appropriate questions on appropriate sites.

Comment: @Lucian The problem with your remark is that you appear to be making a remark about someone of whom English may, or may not, be their first language. There is SE-English Language and Usage, And there is SE-English Language Learners. Which were you suggesting ? And in any case, the user is asking about a situation where there are two Hebrew prepositions and the translators have clearly had difficulty expressing that into English. BH is all about 'vocabulary'. We examine it all the time.

Comment: @NigelJ: I am not a native English speaker either; more to the point, English is not even my first foreign language: what seems to be the problem ? (Language and Usage, since this is clearly a usage question). There was another user on this site, who, despite repeated suggestions to consult Linguistics.SE, simply would not budge; we both know what happened to him.

Comment: @Lucian I am afraid I do not understand the points you are making. No further comment from myself. Regards.

Comment: For my part, I welcome all comments, good or bad, so long as one is sincere about it. We are likely all brothers in Christ. We will have to live with each other for eternity.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to NigelJ's pointer in his comment. There are actually 2 Hebrew prepositions before the noun *mountain*.

אל מול

The second preposition can mean *opposite*.

https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4136.htm, Strong's Exhaustive Concordance

> over against, before, forefront, from, Godward, toward, with
> Or mowl (Deuteronomy 1:1) {mole}; or mowtl (Nehemiah 12:38) {mole}; or mul (Numbers 22:5) {mool}; from muwl; properly, abrupt, i.e. A precipice; by implication, the front; used only adverbially (**with prepositional prefix**) **opposite** -- (over) against, before, (fore-)front, from, (God-)ward, toward, with.

ESV translation of “opposite that mountain” in Exodus 34:3 is justified by מול.